# mount usb as /media/cdrom (replacing the cdrom directory present)

Tags: usb, mount, livedvd, redirect

I have a computer that doesn't want to boot from a usb drive. so I burned a live dvd. problem is that the dvd drive crashes once it heats up so I want the live environment to check the usb drive when it needs any files.
Can I redirect /media/cdrom/ to /media/ubuntu/ubuntu\ live/ ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This...

`# mount --bind "/media/ubuntu/ubuntu live/" /media/cdrom`

...will "bind" mount the former directory in the latter location.

Comment: aaww, unfortunately the live environment still accesses the dvd and not the usb when it needs new files. I also tried replacing `/cdrom` but to no avail. hmm, I'll try to find out where the dvd is mounted. thanks

Comment: I half suspected it might :-(  I guess perhaps the live environment has an "unshared" copy of the file system and the mount isn't having any effect on it. Otherwise, perhaps `mount` will give you a clue as to where else the cdrom is mounted.

Comment: yeah, it has a mount: /dev/sr0 on /cdrom type iso9660 (ro,noatime).  so I'll have to couple /dev/sr0 to /dev/sda1 (I don't have a hard drive atm so it's sda for my usb drive)

Comment: I have made a symbolic link from sda1 to sr0 and it seems to have worked. thanks for your help